# Reporting Services: dynamically add filters to server report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have some server-based reports (*.rdl) which returns data from a SQL Server 2008 view.
The user would like to be able to dynamically add filtering, e.g.

- show me only data with Language = English,
  or
- show me only data for a given organizational unit

or stuff like that. The number of filter criteria is reasonably small (four or five).

But how do I do that?? I have my RDL on the server, with the basic query (`SELECT (fields) FROM MyView WHERE ......`) inside the report data set - how can I dynamically add filtering to that??

I was hoping I might be able to define dataset filters, but those seem to have to be in place when the RDL gets rendered, too (e.g. they become part of the report RDL itself).

The possible values for each criteria are too numerous that I could simply add them as a list and define an `IN (list of values)` kind of filter.....

Any ideas?? Thoughts? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it in the answer space below. Solutions do not belong in questions but in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dynamic (in the sense that the user would have to re-run the report every time), but if you only have four or five parameters with many values the easy solution would be to add a multi-select parameter to the report for each of them which defaults to "All".

Is there a reason why the user can't re-run the report with different parameters?

Or have I misunderstood what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @Ed: for one or two of them, that would work - they only have a handful of possible values. Some however have potentially hundreds or thousands of possible values, so that's not really doable.

Comment: @marc_s: are you concerned about the size of the lists of values because of usability, performance or something else? If usability is the issue, might it be possible to sub-categorise the lists into hierarchies?

Comment: @Ed: both, really - a list with four or five entries is okay, but if it's hundreds or more, it's neither really manageable (for the user) nor really good for performance....

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question :

you can use parameters for filtering. if you have an application that use ReportViewer control for showing report, pass this conditions as parameter to your report. you can manage visibility or data filtering by this parameters.